# Onboarding individual users with Stripe Connect Express

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm developing a C2C marketplace app with Symfony and powered by Stripe Connect Express.
I did a quick POC yesterday and I'm trying to understand how to onboard individual sellers (C2C sales, classifieds style). I did set `'business_type' => 'individual'` in the `Account::create` call but nevertheless, Stripe keeps asking for the MCC (activity code). Individual sellers are selling their own pre-owned stuff, they don't have MCC.

```
$account = [
        'country'           => 'FR',
        'type'              => 'express',
        'email'             => 'test@domain.com',
        'default_currency'  => 'EUR',
        'capabilities' => [
            'card_payments' => ['requested' => true],
            'transfers' => ['requested' => true],
        ],
        'business_type' => 'individual',
        'individual'    => [
            'email'         => 'test@domain.fr',
            'first_name'    => 'John',
            'last_name'     => 'Doe',
        ...
];
$account = $stripe->accounts->create($account);
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply creating an Account is not enough, you also need to onboard users onto your platform for verification using [Account Links](https://stripe.com/docs/api/account_links). The accounts will be in a restricted state and unable to accept payments until verification is complete. The process for doing this with Express accounts is outlined [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#create-link).

You can use the data from [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing) during the hosted onboarding flow to quickly verify test accounts. The account MCC is computed from fields selected by the user during the onboarding flow, you do not need to provide tis manually but it will be [required](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-verification-information#FR-full-individual--card_payments%7Ctransfers).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I did this. Account::create and Link. I redirect the user to the completion steps. And I get a "Industry" step where I must pick an industry (MCC code). As an individual, I shouldn't have to pick an industry, right?